# How to upgrade from tailwindcss 2 to 3 and create-react-app 4.0.3 to 5.0.0 (due to Post CSS 8 )

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, tailwind-css

I created a project via create-react-app 4.0.3 which uses tailwindcss 2. I just tried to upgrade the project to tailwindcss 3, but quickly ran into troubles, since tailwindcss 3 relies on Post CSS 8, which is not supported by create-react-app 4.0.3 , so I also needed to upgrade to create-react-app 5.0.0

The official Create-React-App documentation says "*In most cases bumping the `react-scripts` version in `package.json` and running `npm install` in this folder should be enough, but it’s good to consult the changelog for potential breaking changes.*"

The official Tailwind Upgrade Guide says "*update Tailwind, as well as PostCSS and autoprefixer, using npm*" and adds to that some minor changes in `tailwind.config.js`

I followed this steps and ended up with a huge error message when trying to run `npm run start`

I am thinking that in the end it might be easier to set up the project from a fresh 5.0.0 create-react-app installation, where I install tailwind 3 on top instead of trying to repair all the issues that were caused by the upgrade.

However, before I do this I wanted to ask: What is the recommended solution for upgrading from tailwind 2 to 3 AND upgrade from create-react-app from 4.0.3 to 5.0.0 (since my understanding is that you need to do both to make tailwind work). How did other people solve the issues laid out above?

Comment: I can report having trouble setting up CRA 5/Tailwind 3 setup from scratch too. Still troubleshooting. Curious if you tried creating new project and if it worked for you? I'm using Linux and Node 17.3 and Typescript.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to update react-scripts to version 5.0.0

Then uninstall craco

Finally update tailwind with the command

```
npm install -D tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest
```

You can also follow official guide at https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrade-guide to update the new color names and update the tailwind.config.js file

Now yo can run the command `npm run start` to see the changes and in the console you can see the new build process